# Random web-page flicker when scrolling to the bottom

Tags: wordpress, scroll, flicker

On the web-site I'm working on (wordpress) there is a flicker effect (it is impossible to reach the end of the page since it returns one step back) when the page is scrolled down to the end.
If during this flicker problem I re-size the browser window (normally reduce the size) all works fine.
I noticed that this problem is not browser dependent.

Here is my browse size specs when flicker is there:
Browser window width:   1428
Browser window height:  756
Screen width:   1920
Screen height:  1200

Please help to fix it :)

Comment: I think we're going to need some more info. Are you using a plugin or anything?

Comment: Is it possible for you to include a link to the website? I know exactly the effect you mean as I've seen it before. It can be caused by a few things so I'd need to see the site to identify why its happening for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I know whats happening because it looks identical to the issue I had:

1. When you scroll down, the navbar is been taken out of the flow to be
   made a sticky nav and this changes the page height.
2. However at a certain point, this height change triggers an event
   that causes the navbar to be added back in...
3. ...which increases the page height and triggers the navbar to be removed again...
4. ...and repeat ad nauseum

In my case it was a discrepancy between the height at which the navbar was to be removed and the actual height of the navbar (i.e. the size that was being removed from the page).

You haven't posted your code, so I can't see exactly what you need to change - its a balance between the heights, offsets, breakpoints etc.

An alternative workaround would be to insert a "placeholder" div the same height as the navbar when you remove the navbar from the flow.

Either way, you know whats causing it now so that should be enough to point you in the right direction!

Comment: You are pointing in the right direction. As soon as I disabled sticky navbar the flicker stopped. Now, I found in style.css section dedicated to sticky header styling, however, can't determine threshold variable responsible for navbar removal. More guidance is greatly appreciated. I was not able to fit code in this message due to the characters limit.... How can I share it with you?

Comment: @ART, you can edit your question to include the CSS. But its more likely that the trigger is happening in javascript or jQuery, so take a look at the code you added that detected the scrolling and include it as well.

Comment: I am very new to CSS and js. I was using a downloaded template for my Django application and went into this trauma of page flicker. The issue @FluffyKitten pointed out saved a lot of my time and stress